# Docker with nginx proxy does not work, it is redirecting to an internal host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, docker-machine

I have a structure of containers that are mainly accessed from the outside by means of a main container with nginx working as a reverse proxy.

The problem is that when trying to enter a subfolder it redirects me to an internal url, for example:

If I try to access "http://php.example.com/" it works correctly but if I try to access "http://php.example.com/users/" then it redirects me to "http://php_container" which is the name of my container in php.

My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  custom_network:

services:

  reverse_proxy:
    container_name: proxy_container
    image: nginx:1.17.9
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx
    networks:
      - custom_network
    command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'


  php:
    container_name: php_container
    image: php:7.4.4-apache
    volumes:
      - "./app/php:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      - custom_network
```

My configuration in nginx is as follows:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  server_name php.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://php_container:80;
    proxy_redirect     off;
  }

}

server {

  listen 443;

  server_name php.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://php_container:443;
    proxy_redirect      off;
  }

}
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `proxy_redirect` set to `off`. The `proxy_redirect` directive is there to correct exactly this type of problem. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

Comment: I tell you that I manage to make url work but only when they are in this format "http://php.example.com/users/index.php" but when I try to access "http://php.example.com/users" the exact same thing keeps happening :(

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you should use service name, not container name, so change in config file http://php_container:80; to http://php:80;

Comment: I tried to make that change but it keeps passing the same error only now it redirects me to http://php

Comment: can you try to add on service reverse_proxy:
    links:
      - php